# How can I redirect some sitemap.xml urls from a sub domain to the main domain in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, sitemap

I have a Wordpress installation on a sub domain of my website as I'm using it as a headless CMS. I have the main app that consumes the headless CMS deployed to Vercel hosting. Vercel doesn't let me add xml sitemaps.

I have some xml sitemaps sitting on the sub domain. Is it possible to use .htaccess to rewrite/redirect the urls of these sitemaps on the sub domain to my main domain?

Assuming my sitemap is on the sub domain like this https://wp.example.net/sitemap.xml and I want to be able to access it at https://example.net/sitemap.xml

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why with .htaccess?  I would change the sitemap generator.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller what or how do you mean?

Comment: If the process that generates the sitemap is creating URLs with the wrong domain, I would fix that process rather than trying to change the file with .htaccess

Comment: Although maybe you mean that the sitemap is just getting generated in the wrong place?

Comment: The sitemap is created in Wordpress and will be on the sub domain where Wordpress is installed. So it creates the URLs based on the Wordpress subdomain. However the page urls  for the React application installed on the main domain mimic those of the subdomain. The react app is hosted on Vercel where I can't add a sitemap.

Comment: So you need to modify the sitemap to not use the subdomain in the URLs it includes in it, but I'm not sure you need to serve it from the main domain as opposed to the subdomain.  If you list it in robots.txt from the main domain, it should be fine to serve it from a subdomain.